# WPF - a preload image or template before TabItem load

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a listbox in TabContorol that bind to a database, it takes a little while to load. i want show a preload image or template before TabItem and listbox loaded and after load became complete the preload image be diasapear. help me plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Trigger in the `ListBox.Style`, and if the ItemSource is null I would rewrite the `ListBox.Template` using a Loading Image instead of the regular ListBox template.

Here's an example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property="{Binding MyList}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <Image Source="loadingImage.gif" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I didn't run this through a compiler so I might have some syntax errors, but it should point you in the right direction.